# How do I write a python code that takes paragraphs as user input?

Tags: string, python-3.x, input, encoding

```
    #python program of cipher text
s =input('Enter the plain Text>> ')#Tuhin T=18,u=19,....
a='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
b='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
c=(int(input('Enter the code: ')))#Ex. 5
for i in range(len(s)):
    j=0
    k=0
    if i%80==0 and i>=80:
        print()
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if s[i]==a[j]:
            if (j+c)<=25:
                print(a[j+c],end="")
                k=1
            if (j+c)>25:
                print(a[26-j-c],end="")
                k=1
        if s[i]==b[j]:
            if (j+c)<=25:
                print(b[j+c],end="")
                k=1
            if (j+c)>25:
                print(b[26-j-c],end="")
                k=1
        elif j==len(a)-1 and k==0:
            print(s[i],end="")
```

For input i need to enter single line inputs but i want to enter texts like this format:

> a German-born physicist, is best known for his famous equation, which
>   has been dubbed as ‘the world’s most famous equation’ – “E=mc2.”
>   Albert Einstein was not very satisfied with Newtonian mechanics, as he
>   thought that these theories were not enough to explain classical
>   mechanics and the electromagnetic field. And this inspired him to
>   develop his singular Theory of Relativity

**It's to be kept in mind that I mostly use Thonny and python IDE**

Comment: If the problem is that you can't break lines with 'enter' key when inputing, you can use the `\n` character to indicate it

Comment: no that's not the problem, i want to input copied paragraphs from pdfs for encoding using cipher but i can't do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved using a loop and interpreting "return keypress" as '\n'.
You can try this code:

```
inp= ''
s = ''
while inp.strip('\n') != 'over and out':
    inp = input() #type over and out to exit loop
    if inp != 'over and out':
        s += inp
print(32*'--')
print(s)
#s=input('Enter the plain Text>> ')#Tuhin T=18,u=19,....
a='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
b='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
c=(int(input('Enter the code: ')))#Ex. 5
for i in range(len(s)):
    j=0
    k=0
    if i%80==0 and i>=80:
        print()
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if s[i]==a[j]:
            if (j+c)<=25:
                print(a[j+c],end="")
                k=1
            if (j+c)>25:
                print(a[26-j-c],end="")
                k=1
        if s[i]==b[j]:
            if (j+c)<=25:
                print(b[j+c],end="")
                k=1
            if (j+c)>25:
                print(b[26-j-c],end="")
                k=1
        elif j==len(a)-1 and k==0:
            print(s[i],end="")
```

[copy-paste-multiline-text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nVe0.png)